# How to copy a range of cell from another workbook and paste it to another one?

Tags: excel, vba, range, copy-paste

I need to update my main file every time a third party sends me an updated version of his input. Therefore, I need to copy-paste the range of this new input in a saved workbook on my computer. The range needs to include all columns and all rows if the value in column A is greater than 0. For example, in the picture below, from A1 to A45.

enter image description here

I found a way to select the rows and stop at the first zero. I've put a sum-product formula on the side that I call in my code i.

For now, I have this code:

I have an error on line 
Set wb2 = Workbooks("20200403 Selina - Loanbook V2.09 (1).xls")

I can't fix it... I have tried ThisWorkbook but nothing, do you have any idea?

Let me know :)

Antoine

```
Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    'Open Workbook from Pepper

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Pepper Automation\Accounts latest\Accounts updated\Accounts_latest.xlsx")

    'Copy Range (Column A to BW - all filled rows)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = Worksheets("Accounts_latest").Range("CA1").Value
    wb1.Worksheets("Accounts_latest").Range("A1:BW" & i).Copy

    'Paste to worksheet in workbook2:
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("20200403 Selina - Loanbook V2.09 (1).xls")
    wb2.Activate
    wb2.Sheets("Pepper Accounts RAW").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("A1").Select

    'Close workbook
    wb1.Close savechanges:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the workbook already open at this time?

Comment: Yes, the second wkb is open and is the one I will using to launch the macro

Comment: Is the second wkb the one that has this code then?

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Yes I ve written this code in the second wkb. The error is: Run-time Error '9'. Subscript out of range

Comment: then there's no open worbook named after _"20200403 Selina - Loanbook V2.09 (1).xls"_ in the **same** Excel session

Comment: `Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: True, what do you reckon I should put to paste it?

Comment: Hey @BigBen, I ve done this and I get: error '-2147418113', Automation error, catastrophic failure

Comment: @AntoineBonin _"True"_ what? Please address your comment by "@" and the name of the user you want to address it to (like "@HTH")

Comment: Move the copy line to right before the paste special.

Comment: hey @HTH, sorry, I agree with your comment that I should not open the workbook named after 20200403 Selina - Loanbook V2.09 (1).xls as it's the one I am using, but when I put Tis Workbook instead I still have an error Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook

Comment: @AntoineBonin, no, my comment was about that the error occurs **because** _"there's no open worbook named after "20200403 Selina - Loanbook V2.09 (1).xls" in the **same** Excel session"_

Comment: What do you mean to the right? @BigBen

Comment: Move the line `wb1.Worksheets("Accounts_latest").Range("A1:BW" & i).Copy` to immediately before `wb2.Sheets("Pepper Accounts RAW").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`. This assumes that you already changed `Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: @BigBen I have updated the code as you advised me : Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    wb2.Activate
    wb1.Worksheets("Accounts_latest").Range("A1:BW" & i).Copy
    wb2.Sheets("Pepper Accounts RAW").Range("A1:BW" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("A1").Select

Comment: @BigBen but I still have the error at SET wb2 = thisworkbook,

Comment: Hmmm - close out of Excel and restart?

Comment: @AntoineBonin what's the error message at `Set wb2 = thisworkbook`?

Comment: @HTH Run time error '-2147418113 (8000ffff)

Comment: @AntoineBonin, then it's different than before.  I'll wait for your update after your _"close out of Excel and restart"_

Comment: @HTH Thanks for your time and help but I still get the same error...

Comment: @AntoineBonin, please always state what message error and which line is thowing it

Answer (score -1):

something like this

```
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("20200403 Selina - Loanbook V2.09 (1).xls")


wb2.Close savechanges:=True
```

Comment: Please add also why/how should this fix things